# How to fix a debug configuration fail with Windows App certification kit?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, windows-phone-8.1, release

I just updated a Windows Phone 8.0 app to 8.1 but when I run the Windows app cert kit its keeps failing with a `failed debug configuration`.

I gathered from this that the project build was set to debug somewhere but from what I can see the release build config settings has been set and the .xap file shows that it is a release version.

[image: debug failure win app test]

Is there another build configuration setting I may have missed that is causing this error?

I've set the build config to release here:

[image: release config]

And also in the project properties :

[image: app property set to release also]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to build a "Release" version of the .xap not just change the settings in the Configuration Manager.

Change it to release by clicking the Drop Down menu next to the Green Arrow, you also might need to change it to ARM as well.

[image]

---

After you compile then you can Store -> Launch Windows App Certification Kit